# Add multiple elements to pathlib path

Tags: python, pathlib

I have a Python pathlib `Path` and a list of strings, and I'd like to concatenate the strings to the path. This works

```py
from pathlib import Path

a = Path("a")
lst = ["b", "c", "d"]

for item in lst:
    a = a / item

print(a)
```

```
a/b/c/d
```

but is a little clumsy. Can the `for` loop be replaced by something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might be what you are after:

```
from pathlib import Path

a = Path("a")
dir_list = ["b", "c", "d"]

a = a.joinpath(*dir_list)
```

Answer (score 4):

The constructor of any [`PurePath`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath) subclass accepts an arbitrary number of positional arguments, which means you can just unpack your list of strings.

```py
from pathlib import Path

a = Path("a")
lst = ["b", "c", "d"]

a = Path(a, *lst)
print(a)  # a/b/c/d
```

Notice that each argument to `Path` can be itself a `Path` instance or a string.